# (EF 4.0 vs a normal SQL) Improve execution time in Linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, linq

When I execute this SQL statement, it takes absolutely no time to run:

```
select * from [user]
left join licence on [user].userID = licence.UserID
left join licenceProducts on licence.licenceID = licenceProducts.licenceID
left join products on products.productID = licenceProducts.productID
left join contacts on contacts.UserID = [user].userID
left join usersupportedproducts on usersupportedproducts.UserID = [user].userID
left join [user] b on b.userID = [user].ParentUserID
where [user].Type <> 6
order by [user].name
```

However, when I run the same query using EF 4.0 it takes almost 20 sec to execute.

Is there a way to improve this Linq request, I tried ?

```
users = null;
using (var db = new DistributorEntities())
{
    try
    {
        users = db.Users
            .Include(u => u.Licences)
            .Include(u => u.Licences.Select(l => l.LicenceProducts.Select(lp => lp.Product)))
            .Include(u => u.UserAddress)
            .Include(u => u.Contact)
            .Include(u => u.User2)
            .Include(u => u.SupportProducts)
            .Where(u => u.Type != (int)UserType.Admin)
            .OrderBy(u => u.Name)
            .ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex is InvalidOperationException)
        {
            _EventLog.WriteEntry(ex.Message + "  WebService.GetAllUsersAndChildren");
        }
        exception = new ServiceError(ex);
    }
}
```

I tried to execute `ExecuteStoreQuery()` by putting my SQl statement, but it does not join the relations of `users`.

Comment: Have you used a SQL Profiler to see what that linq statement generates?

Comment: To me it looks like you are (in your Linq) just eager loading like a crazy man, instead of left joining.

Comment: How to do the left join in this Linq statement?

Comment: @billybob Here's an example from MSDN on how to perform LEFT JOIN in LINQ: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397895.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Writing queries directly in SQL is almost always way more efficient than writing expressions in LINQ which must then be translated into "sub-optimal" SQL.

What you could do is simply create a `VIEW` that contains your query, then map that `VIEW` to an `Entity` in Entity Framework, then query that `Entity` -- which will just execute the `VIEW` in SQL Server.

See also http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1990/how-to-use-sql-server-views-with-the-entity-framework/.

Comment: Using this method will not add the navigation properties.

Comment: However I need to get the navigation properties, so It's not a good approach for what I want to achieve.