# How do I make this Linq to SQL query with lambdas and includes faster?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

I have this piece of code which performs quite poorly, and delays loading of web pages as a result. The objects underlying the query are not overly complicated and I only have around 6,000 rows in the time entry table, and a small number of rows in the included tables.

How can I re-write it to be more efficient? Why is it so slow? Is it the multiple includes, the lambdas, or the `ToList()`? When I remove the `ToList()` it is quite fast, but the code following this query expects a list of time entries, so I would like to find a faster alternative that still returns a list.

```
var timeEntries = db.TimeEntries
    .Include(t => t.Assignment)
    .Include(t => t.TimeStatus)
    .Include(t => t.User)
    .Where(t => t.UserID == strCurrentUserId)
    .Where(t => t.TimeDate >= wcDate && t.TimeDate <= sundayDate)
    .OrderBy(t => t.TimeDate)
    .ToList();
```

A few of the classes are below (but, I'm not exposing my user class):

```
public class TimeEntry
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int AssignmentID { get; set; }
    public virtual Assignment Assignment { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeDate { get; set; }
    public decimal TimeUsed { get; set; }
    public int TimeStatusID { get; set; }
    public TimeStatus TimeStatus { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}

public class TimeStatus
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

public class Assignment
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public int AssignmentStatusID { get; set; }
    public AssignmentStatus AssignmentStatus { get; set; }
    public decimal ChargeRate { get; set; }
    public int MaxDays { get; set; }
    public bool Billable { get; set; }
    public bool BillableInternal { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Assignment No.")]
    public string AssignmentNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return "A" + ID.ToString("D5");
        }
        set { }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that the `Include` might be the reason. Do you need all columns/properties from Assignment, TimeStatus,  User and TimeEntry? Or just some of them?

Comment: It is faster when you remove ToList() because the query execution is deferred until you actually use the results.  That mean the query doesn't run until you call ToList() or otherwise start consuming results.

Comment: Get the SQL that gets executed and run it yourself and check the execution plan.  I suspect a few indexes might speed it up.  (My guess would be to put one on TimeDate, but without the execution plan I can't be sure.)

Comment: It would help if you posted the definitions of `TimeEntries`, `Assignment`, `TimeStatus`, and `User`. Without that information you'll only get wild guesses. Adding a `.Select` to reduce the amount of data might help. Making sure the join columns and criteria columns are indexed might help.

Comment: Further, if you don't need all 6000 rows at one time, you can Skip(200) and Take(20) or whatever you actually need (AKA paging).

Comment: Looks to me like you could get a win with an index on TimeDate. Maybe an index on UserId, as well. That'd be on the DB side, though. If that doesn't help (or is already in place), then I'd look at how you can cut down on the data returned (not including every column of every table and/or putting off loading associated table data and using AJAX calls when they're needed for display).

Comment: I had the same problem. use a store proc. or create a view. Here's the thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19708136/ef-4-0-vs-a-normal-sql-improve-execution-time-in-linq

Comment: juharr - thanks for reformatting, much more readable now :-). Everyone else, thanks for the tips. Yaocub - no I don't need all the properties of each object. Not all 6000 will be returned in this query, as it is limited by date and userId, but I will require all those returned within those constraints. AssignmentId, TimeStatusID and UserId are indexed already, but not TimeDate.

Comment: I have to agree with billybob - Linq queries should be limited to simple queries.  Complex queries should be done inside a database stored proc, which will execute it WAY faster natively.

Comment: Thanks David/Billy I will look at trying that out. I have some stored procedure code for reports which is complex logically, but each one returns a simple dataset. Seems like a similar approach will help me to optimise the performance as you suggest.